# customize childrow of expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-imageview, layout-inflater

I'm working on expandable listview. I need to display different images in imageview of the childview(child_row) based on my database value. I tried to set image, but nothing works..

Any help on this?? Thanks in advance....

ExpandableListActivity.java

```
public class ExpList extends ExpandableListActivity
{
    String parent_node[];   
    String custom_child[][][][];

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    

        SimpleExpandableListAdapterWithEmptyGroups expListAdapter =
                new SimpleExpandableListAdapterWithEmptyGroups(
                    this,
                    createGroupList(),                      
                    R.layout.group_row,                     
                    new String[] { "colorName" },           
                    new int[] { R.id.groupname },   
                    createChildList2(),
                    R.layout.child_row,
                    new String[] { "name", "number", "date", "time"},
                    new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.number,R.id.date, R.id.time}
                );
            setListAdapter( expListAdapter );

// I tried all following methods to put different image in imageview, but not working. 

 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);

             ImageView img_call = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.img_call_icon);
             img_call.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.skype);
             Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.skype);
             img_call.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
             img_call.setImageResource(R.drawable.skype);
             img_call.setImageDrawable(d);
}   
 }
```

child_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_call_type"
        android:src="@drawable/incoming_call"
        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="40px"/>

         <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/space"                     
         android:layout_width="10px"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/name"         
             android:textSize="14px"             
             android:layout_width="115px"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
             android:id="@+id/number"
             android:textSize="14px"             
             android:layout_width="115px"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/date"         
             android:textSize="14px"          
             android:layout_width="115px"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

        <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/time"
             android:textSize="14px"         
             android:layout_width="115px"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />        

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- This is imageview in which I need to display diffrent images -->
        <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_call_icon"

        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClickHandler"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class TempExpandableListActivity extends Activity {
ExpandableListView expd;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> childrenbillableList,childrentaskList,childrenprojectList,childrentimeList;
public static ArrayList<String>
enddateList,isbillableList,projectidList,projectnameList,startdateList,
starttimeList,starttimeList24,stoptimeList,stoptimeList24,taskidList,tasknameList,totalhoursList,trackdescriptionList,
trackidList,trackprojectidList,tracktaskidList,parentdatelist,differencelist,sortedfinalhrslist;
public static ArrayList<Integer>differList,temptimeList,sortedtotalhrsList;
public static ArrayList<String>tempbillableList,temptasklist,tempprojectList,temptime1List;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    expd=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandable);
    temptime1List=new ArrayList<String>();
    tempbillableList=new ArrayList<String>();
    temptasklist=new ArrayList<String>();
    tempprojectList=new ArrayList<String>();
    childrenbillableList=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    childrentaskList=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    childrenprojectList=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    childrentimeList=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    sortedtotalhrsList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    sortedfinalhrslist=new ArrayList<String>();
    temptimeList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    differList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    differencelist=new ArrayList<String>();
    starttimeList24=new ArrayList<String>();
    stoptimeList24=new ArrayList<String>();
    parentdatelist=new ArrayList<String>();
    enddateList=new ArrayList<String>();
    isbillableList=new ArrayList<String>();
    projectidList=new ArrayList<String>();
    projectnameList=new ArrayList<String>();
    startdateList=new ArrayList<String>();
    starttimeList=new ArrayList<String>();
    stoptimeList=new ArrayList<String>();
    taskidList=new ArrayList<String>();
    tasknameList=new ArrayList<String>();
    totalhoursList=new ArrayList<String>();
    trackdescriptionList=new ArrayList<String>();
    trackidList=new ArrayList<String>();
    trackprojectidList=new ArrayList<String>();
    tracktaskidList=new ArrayList<String>();
    new BackgroundTask().execute();
}
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void >  
{
      private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(TempExpandableListActivity.this);

      protected void onPreExecute() 
      {

             Dialog.setMessage("Downloading");
             Dialog.show();
      }

      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
      {
         // write here the code to download  or to perform any background task.
          childrenbillableList.clear();
          childrenprojectList.clear();
          childrentaskList.clear();
          childrentimeList.clear();
          sortedfinalhrslist.clear();
          differencelist.clear();
          differList.clear();
          parentdatelist.clear();
          sortedtotalhrsList.clear();
          enddateList.clear();
          starttimeList24.clear();
          stoptimeList24.clear();
          isbillableList.clear();
          projectidList.clear();
          projectnameList.clear();
          startdateList.clear();
          starttimeList.clear();
          stoptimeList.clear();
          taskidList.clear();
          tasknameList.clear();
          totalhoursList.clear();
          trackdescriptionList.clear();
          trackidList.clear();
          trackprojectidList.clear();
          tracktaskidList.clear();

          getTimeEntryInfo();  
          for(int i=0;i<startdateList.size();i++)
            {
                if(!parentdatelist.contains(startdateList.get(i)))
                {
                    parentdatelist.add(startdateList.get(i));
                }


                }
        for(int i=0;i<parentdatelist.size();i++)
        {
            temptime1List.clear();
            temptimeList.clear();  
            tempbillableList.clear();
            temptasklist.clear();
            tempprojectList.clear();
            for(int j=0;j<startdateList.size();j++)
            {
            if(parentdatelist.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(startdateList.get(j)))    
            {
                int total=differList.get(j);
                temptimeList.add(total);
                //children.add(object);temptime1List
                 int hr=total/60;
                 int mi=total%60;
                 String temh=String.valueOf(hr);
                 String temmi=String.valueOf(mi);
                 if(temh.length()== 1)
                 {
                     temh="0"+temh; 
                 }
                 if(temmi.length()== 1)
                 {
                     temmi="0"+temmi; 
                 }

                 temptime1List.add(temh+":"+temmi);
                tempbillableList.add(isbillableList.get(j));
                temptasklist.add(tasknameList.get(j));
                tempprojectList.add(projectnameList.get(j));

            }

            }

            childrenbillableList.add(tempbillableList);
            tempbillableList=new ArrayList<String>();
            childrenprojectList.add(tempprojectList);
            tempprojectList=new ArrayList<String>();
            childrentaskList.add(temptasklist);
            temptasklist=new ArrayList<String>();
            childrentimeList.add(temptime1List);
            temptime1List=new ArrayList<String>();


            int temp =0;
            if(temptimeList.size()>0)
            {
            for(int x=0;x<temptimeList.size();x++)
            {
                if(temptimeList.size()==1)
                {
                    temp=temptimeList.get(x);
                }
                else
                {
                 temp=temp+temptimeList.get(x);
                }
            }
          sortedtotalhrsList.add(temp);
            }
        }
         for(int z=0;z<sortedtotalhrsList.size();z++)
         {
             int hrs=sortedtotalhrsList.get(z)/60;
             int min=sortedtotalhrsList.get(z)%60;
             String temhr=String.valueOf(hrs);
             String temmin=String.valueOf(min);
             if(temhr.length()== 1)
             {
                 temhr="0"+temhr; 
             }
             if(temmin.length()== 1)
             {
                 temmin="0"+temmin; 
             }
           sortedfinalhrslist.add(temhr+":"+temmin+" "+"hr");


         }
            return null;
    }

      protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) 
      {
          Dialog.dismiss();
          expd.setAdapter(new ExpandableAdapter());


      }

    }   
public class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childrenbillableList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosition;
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder1 holder1;
        LayoutInflater  inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
            holder1 = new ViewHolder1();

        }
        else
        {
            holder1 = (ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag();
        }
            holder1.dollar=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.isbillable);
            holder1.taskname=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskname);
            holder1.projectname=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.projectname);
            holder1.tasktime=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tasktime);
            if(childrenbillableList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
            {
                holder1.dollar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                holder1.dollar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            holder1.taskname.setText(childrentaskList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
            holder1.projectname.setText(childrenprojectList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
            holder1.tasktime.setText(childrentimeList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));

            convertView.setTag(holder1);

        return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder1 {  
         ImageView dollar;
         TextView taskname;
         TextView projectname;
         TextView tasktime;
         }
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childrenbillableList.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return parentdatelist.get(groupPosition);
    }  

    public int getGroupCount() {                     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return parentdatelist.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {   
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater  inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
        }
         else
         {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         }
        holder.day=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);
        holder.time=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        holder.day.setText(parentdatelist.get(groupPosition));
        holder.time.setText(sortedfinalhrslist.get(groupPosition));
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        return convertView;
    }
 class ViewHolder {  

         TextView day;
         TextView time;

         }
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
public void getTimeEntryInfo()
{


                                    enddateList.add("02/08/2012");
                                    enddateList.add("02/07/2012");
                                    enddateList.add("02/07/2012");
                                    enddateList.add("02/07/2012");
                                    enddateList.add("02/07/2012");
                                    enddateList.add("02/07/2012");
                                    enddateList.add("02/06/2012");
                                    enddateList.add("02/02/2012");
                                    enddateList.add("02/02/2012");
                                    enddateList.add("01/31/2012");
                                    enddateList.add("01/30/2012");
                                    enddateList.add("01/30/2012");
                                    enddateList.add("01/30/2012");

                                    isbillableList.add("false");
                                    isbillableList.add("false");
                                    isbillableList.add("false");
                                    isbillableList.add("false");
                                    isbillableList.add("false");
                                    isbillableList.add("false");
                                    isbillableList.add("false");
                                    isbillableList.add("false");
                                    isbillableList.add("false");
                                    isbillableList.add("false");
                                    isbillableList.add("false");
                                    isbillableList.add("false");
                                    isbillableList.add("false");


                                    projectidList.add("16");
                                    projectidList.add("0");
                                    projectidList.add("0");
                                    projectidList.add("7");
                                    projectidList.add("7");
                                    projectidList.add("7");
                                    projectidList.add("7");
                                    projectidList.add("0");
                                    projectidList.add("0");
                                    projectidList.add("7");
                                    projectidList.add("0");
                                    projectidList.add("0");
                                    projectidList.add("6");


                                    projectnameList.add("4FebNewProject");
                                    projectnameList.add("NO DESCRIPTION");
                                    projectnameList.add("NO DESCRIPTION");
                                    projectnameList.add("Coggl Company Admin");
                                    projectnameList.add("Coggl Company Admin");
                                    projectnameList.add("Coggl Company Admin");
                                    projectnameList.add("Coggl Company Admin");
                                    projectnameList.add("NO DESCRIPTION");
                                    projectnameList.add("NO DESCRIPTION");
                                    projectnameList.add("Test Project1");
                                    projectnameList.add("NO DESCRIPTION");
                                    projectnameList.add("NO DESCRIPTION");
                                    projectnameList.add("Test Project");


                                    startdateList.add("02/07/2012");
                                    startdateList.add("02/07/2012");
                                    startdateList.add("02/07/2012");
                                    startdateList.add("02/07/2012");
                                    startdateList.add("02/06/2012");
                                    startdateList.add("02/07/2012");
                                    startdateList.add("02/06/2012");
                                    startdateList.add("02/02/2012");
                                    startdateList.add("02/02/2012");
                                    startdateList.add("01/30/2012");
                                    startdateList.add("01/30/2012");
                                    startdateList.add("01/30/2012");
                                    startdateList.add("01/30/2012");


                                    starttimeList.add("9:45 PM");
                                    starttimeList.add("9:19 AM");
                                    starttimeList.add("9:18 AM");
                                    starttimeList.add("5:52 AM");
                                    starttimeList.add("9:33 PM");
                                    starttimeList.add("5:25 AM");
                                    starttimeList.add("1:04 AM");
                                    starttimeList.add("1:52 AM");
                                    starttimeList.add("1:51 AM");
                                    starttimeList.add("1:18 PM");
                                    starttimeList.add("12:56 PM");
                                    starttimeList.add("5:10 AM");
                                    starttimeList.add("11:29 AM");


                                    stoptimeList.add("11:43 PM");
                                    stoptimeList.add("9:19 AM");
                                    stoptimeList.add("9:18 AM");
                                    stoptimeList.add("5:52 AM");
                                    stoptimeList.add("3:44 AM");
                                    stoptimeList.add("5:27 AM");
                                    stoptimeList.add("2:04 AM");
                                    stoptimeList.add("1:52 AM");
                                    stoptimeList.add("1:52 AM");
                                    stoptimeList.add("1:21 PM");
                                    stoptimeList.add("12:56 PM");
                                    stoptimeList.add("12:58 PM");
                                    stoptimeList.add("11:29 AM");


                                    taskidList.add("9");
                                    taskidList.add("0");
                                    taskidList.add("0");
                                    taskidList.add("2");
                                    taskidList.add("1");
                                    taskidList.add("13");
                                    taskidList.add("2");
                                    taskidList.add("0");
                                    taskidList.add("0");
                                    taskidList.add("4");
                                    taskidList.add("0");
                                    taskidList.add("0");
                                    taskidList.add("1");


                                    tasknameList.add("New Task......");
                                    tasknameList.add("NO TASK");
                                    tasknameList.add("NO TASK");
                                    tasknameList.add("Create Company Admin Dashboard");
                                    tasknameList.add("Create Company Admin Login Screen");
                                    tasknameList.add("Create Company Admin Dashboard");
                                    tasknameList.add("Create Company Admin Dashboard");
                                    tasknameList.add("NO TASK");
                                    tasknameList.add("NO TASK");
                                    tasknameList.add("Design");
                                    tasknameList.add("NO TASK");
                                    tasknameList.add("NO TASK");
                                    tasknameList.add("Development");


                                    totalhoursList.add("7080");
                                    totalhoursList.add("0");
                                    totalhoursList.add("19");
                                    totalhoursList.add("0");
                                    totalhoursList.add("22260");
                                    totalhoursList.add("120");
                                    totalhoursList.add("3621");
                                    totalhoursList.add("8");
                                    totalhoursList.add("7");
                                    totalhoursList.add("180");
                                    totalhoursList.add("8");
                                    totalhoursList.add("2880");
                                    totalhoursList.add("9");


                                    trackdescriptionList.add("eryewr bewryer1s");
                                    trackdescriptionList.add("eryewr bewryer1");
                                    trackdescriptionList.add("No Description");
                                    trackdescriptionList.add("test1233");
                                    trackdescriptionList.add("Careful");
                                    trackdescriptionList.add("New Test Job");
                                    trackdescriptionList.add("test");
                                    trackdescriptionList.add("No Description");
                                    trackdescriptionList.add("fgfdsgfd");
                                    trackdescriptionList.add("Design Test");
                                    trackdescriptionList.add("123456");
                                    trackdescriptionList.add("New Test232");
                                    trackdescriptionList.add("New Test232");


                                    trackidList.add("149");
                                    trackidList.add("147");
                                    trackidList.add("146");
                                    trackidList.add("142");
                                    trackidList.add("141");
                                    trackidList.add("140");
                                    trackidList.add("139");
                                    trackidList.add("137");
                                    trackidList.add("136");
                                    trackidList.add("127");
                                    trackidList.add("126");
                                    trackidList.add("125");
                                    trackidList.add("124");


                                    trackprojectidList.add("72");
                                    trackprojectidList.add("0");
                                    trackprojectidList.add("0");
                                    trackprojectidList.add("69");
                                    trackprojectidList.add("68");
                                    trackprojectidList.add("67");
                                    trackprojectidList.add("66");
                                    trackprojectidList.add("0");
                                    trackprojectidList.add("0");
                                    trackprojectidList.add("65");
                                    trackprojectidList.add("0");
                                    trackprojectidList.add("0");
                                    trackprojectidList.add("64");


                                    tracktaskidList.add("55");
                                    tracktaskidList.add("0");
                                    tracktaskidList.add("0");
                                    tracktaskidList.add("54");
                                    tracktaskidList.add("53");
                                    tracktaskidList.add("52");
                                    tracktaskidList.add("51");
                                    tracktaskidList.add("0");
                                    tracktaskidList.add("0");
                                    tracktaskidList.add("50");
                                    tracktaskidList.add("0");
                                    tracktaskidList.add("0");
                                    tracktaskidList.add("49");

                                    SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                                    SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

                                    for(int i=0;i<starttimeList.size();i++)
                                    {
                                        Date stdate = null;
                                        try {
                                            stdate = parseFormat.parse(starttimeList.get(i));
                                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        String st24time=displayFormat.format(stdate);
                                        starttimeList24.add(st24time);

                                        Date etdate = null;
                                        try {
                                            etdate = parseFormat.parse(stoptimeList.get(i));
                                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        String et24time=displayFormat.format(etdate);
                                        stoptimeList24.add(et24time);

                                        String edate[]=enddateList.get(i).split("/");
                                        String etime[]=et24time.split(":");
                                        String sdate[]=startdateList.get(i).split("/");
                                        String stime[]=st24time.split(":");

                                        Date ed = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(edate[2]), Integer.parseInt(edate[0]),Integer.parseInt(edate[1]), Integer.parseInt(etime[0]), Integer.parseInt(etime[1])).getTime();

                                        Date sd = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(sdate[2]), Integer.parseInt(sdate[0]),Integer.parseInt(sdate[1]), Integer.parseInt(stime[0]), Integer.parseInt(stime[1])).getTime();
                                     int diffmin= (int) ((ed.getTime() - sd.getTime())/60000);

                                      int hrs=diffmin/60;
                                     int min=diffmin%60;

                                    differList.add(diffmin);
                                    differencelist.add(hrs+":"+min);                      
                                    }





                                    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
        here is the xml files

`// main.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <ExpandableListView 

                 android:id="@+id/expandable"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                 />
    </LinearLayout>


       //parent.xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="#5cb3ff"
             android:padding="5dp"
            >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/day"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Weekday"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                />
             <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Time"
                />
            </RelativeLayout>
        `//child.xml

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="#ffffff"
             android:padding="5dp"
            >
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/isbillable"
                android:src="@drawable/dollar_sign"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                />
            <TextView 

                android:textColor="#5cb3ff"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/isbillable"
                android:id="@+id/taskname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Designing New Layout" 
            android:textStyle="bold"

                />
            <TextView 
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_below="@+id/taskname"

                android:id="@+id/projectname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Cognitter Coggl_Stanley Design"


                />
            <TextView 
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/tasktime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Time"


                />

            </RelativeLayout>
        `


        `
```